# Control how numpy casts a type via custom function

Tags: python, numpy, oop, types, numpy-ndarray

When you call `np.array` on an iterable of objects, it tries to cast all of them to the same type. So, for example, an iterable of several integers and one float will all be cast to floats.

```
>>> np.array([[1, 2],[3, 4.0]])
array([[1., 2.],
       [3., 4.]])
```

But I want to find a way to have custom types, which define how they are cast.

**Essentially:**

```
    class custom():

        def __init__(self, x):
            self.x = x

        def __as_numpy_value__(self): # This is the function I want!
            return f(self.x)

        def f(self):
            # some arbitrary tranformation of x
            # into a valid input for np.array
```

`f(self)` might be a single value or a list...

```
class Expandable():
    def __as_numpy_value__(self):
        return [1,2,3]

>>> x = Expandable()
>>> np.array([x, x, x, [4, 5, 6]])
array([[1, 2, 3],
        [1, 2, 3],
        [1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6]])
```

Ideally, there would be some way to simply add a method to my class. If this requires subclassing np.array (or its constructor(?)) that would be fine, too.

**EDIT: Some specific examples of what I want to do...**

```
class SpecialFraction(fractions.Fraction):

    def __as_numpy_value__(self):
        return [self.numerator, self.denominator]

>>> np.array(SpecialFraction(1/2))
array([1,2])

class SpecialTuple(tuple):

    def __as_numpy_value__(self):
        np_val = []
        for x in self:
            if x is not None:
                np_val.append(x+0j)
            else:
                np_val.append(0+1j)
        return np_val

>>> np.array(SpecialTuple((None, 1)))
array([0+1j, 1+0j])
```

**EDIT: The most generalized version of my question**

Does Numpy include any built-in facility for custom-defining how user-defined types are treated when they are brought into an array?

In other words... is there any real-life equivalent of my fantasy dunder method `__as_numpy_value__`.

Comment: Can't the `dtype` parameter do the job for you?  `np.array([[1, 2],[3, 4.0]],int)`

Comment: Could you please give us an idea of what your class looks like and what casting you would like to implement?

Comment: `dtype` doesn't allow me to transform the object at casting, as the example shows.

Comment: I did give an idea, in the question text. There's several different cases where I want to be able to do this, so I asked the question in a general purpose way. One specific case is a custom type which is a subclass of `fractions.Fraction`, which I want to get cast as if it were a two-element iterable: `np.array(SpecialFraction(1,4)) == np.array([1,4])`.